# how to redirect a page through controller in zend

Tags: zend-framework, redirect

When I click on a submit button i want the page to redirect to the following page?

```
header('Location: /pdp/policy-info.phtml');
```

I wrote the above code in the controller code but I am not able to redirect  to the above page. it stays on the same page.
the filename is called policy-info.phtml in the view.

Also once I redirect, would I be able access my form values through $_POST?
Or is there an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok it sounds to me like you may be missing a few concepts:

- You will never redirect to a phtml file. (unless you have written some custom rewrite/route rules) Zend uses the MVC architecture, urls exist in this fashion:

  ```
  /module/controller/view/key1/value1/keyx/valuex/
  ```

  generally zend urls don't terminate with file extensions. Also you will never directly call a view file from your browser.
- In your form tag, you specify where the form submits to with the action attribute. For your url i'm assuming the pdp controller and policy-info action

```
    action="/pdp/policy-info/"
```

- If you want to redirect after a form submit from with your controller you would use:

```
    $this->_redirect('/pdp/policy-info/'); 

    # maybe you want to execute some code and then execute 
    # additional code in another controller without re-bootstrapping
    $this->_forward('policy-info', 'pdp');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods

- If you redirect you will not have access to your POST unless you saved those values elsewhere (like in your session). If you forward, I believe the values will still be available in the second action.

Comment: the only option have is redirect.since i am doing error checking and validating and displaying it in the form page. I wish there was another way around other than session. Can you please provide me an example as how to use $_SESSION like post in zend?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html is going to be your best explanation. in zend you generally wont use $_SESSION, "while $_SESSION is still available in PHP's global namespace, developers should refrain from directly accessing it".

Answer (score 0):

actually there maybe a few ways to do what you want to do. I haven't tried this first method yet but it should work.

- Render a new veiw script from your controller/action if isPost():

  ```
  public function myAction(){
  $form = My_Form();
  $this->view->form = $form;

  //if form is posted and submit = Submit
  if ($this_request->isPost() && $this_request->getPost()->submit == 'Submit') {
      if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()) {
      //this is where you want to capture form data
      $data = $form->getValues();
      //render a new viewscript or _forward to a new action and perform your processing there.
      $this->render('path to phtml file');
      //if user needs to press a button to accept submit = accept
      ...do some more stuff...
          }
      }    
  }
  ```

  I think this or some variation will work.
  **Note:** I don't think _forward resets the request object, so your $_POST data should not be affected.

Also if this policy-info does not require additional input from the user and is just informational you could easily just `_forward('action')` to a blank action and the router will display the view script.